# Batch rename pdf files (IEEE articles)

Tags: pdf, rename, ieee

I have a very large number (thousands) of pdf files downloaded from IEEE Xplore.

The filenames only contain the article number of the file. For example

6215021.pdf

Now if you visit

http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=6215021

you can find all the information available about this article.

If you check the site source code you can find the section bellow:

```
        <meta name="citation_title" content="Decomposition-Based Distributed Control for Continuous-Time Multi-Agent Systems">
        <meta name="citation_date" content="Jan. 2013">
        <meta name="citation_volume" content="58">
        <meta name="citation_issue" content="1">
        <meta name="citation_firstpage" content="258">
        <meta name="citation_lastpage" content="264">
        <meta name="citation_doi" content="10.1109/TAC.2012.2204153">
        <meta name="citation_abstract_html_url" content="http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6215021' escapeXml='false'/>">
        <meta name="citation_pdf_url" content="http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/9/6384835/06215021.pdf?arnumber=6215021">
        <meta name="citation_issn" content="0018-9286">
        <meta name="citation_isbn" content="">
        <meta name="citation_language" content="English">
        <meta name="citation_keywords" content="
        Distributed control;
        Output feedback;
        Satellites;
        Stability criteria;
        Standards;
        State feedback;
        Upper bound;
        Distributed control;
        linear matrix inequality (LMI);
        multi-agent systems;
        robust control;">
```

I would like to rename the files I have as "firstpage - citation_title.pdf"

My programming skills are limited (some C only, no clue about parsing) so I am counting on your help.

Thank all of you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can compile the following C# code by using the [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) library.
It renames all of the PDF files in a directory based on the meta data of the PDF files, including their subjects or titles.

```
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace BatchRename
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string getTitle(PdfReader reader)
        {
            string title;
            reader.Info.TryGetValue("Title", out title); // Reading PDF file's meta data
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title) ? string.Empty : title.Trim();
        }

        private static string getSubject(PdfReader reader)
        {
            string subject;
            reader.Info.TryGetValue("Subject", out subject); // Reading PDF file's meta data
            return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subject) ? string.Empty : subject.Trim();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dir = @"D:\Prog\1390\iTextSharpTests\BatchRename\bin\Release";
            if (!dir.EndsWith(@"\"))
                dir = dir + @"\";

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.pdf"))
            {
                var reader = new PdfReader(file);
                var title = getTitle(reader);
                var subject = getSubject(reader);
                reader.Close();

                string newFile = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
                {
                    newFile = dir + title + ".pdf";
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subject))
                {
                    newFile = dir + subject + ".pdf";
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newFile))
                    File.Move(file, newFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code in python.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Created on Sep 28, 2013

@author: dataq <http://stackoverflow.com/users/2585246/dataq>

This is a simple code to rename the paper based on the ORIGINAL FILENAME and their website.
Your are free to use this code, but don't blame me for the error.
I am not writing any documentation, so please read my mind in this code.
USE ON YOUR OWN RISK *evil smirk*
'''
import urllib2, re, time, random
from os import listdir, rename
from os.path import isfile, join

# for every publisher we have different way of scraping
IEEE = 1
SCIENCEDIRECT = 2

# yes, I know, this very bad and stupid web scraping. But it's work at least.

# get title for IEEE paper
# the IEEE paper filename is looks like this '06089032.pdf'
def getIEEETitle(fname):
    # get url
    number = int(fname.split('.')[0])    
    targeturl = 'http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber='+str(number)
    # open and read from those url
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    ieeePage = opener.open(targeturl).read()
    # split  every tag in the html. this is the stupid part :p
    ieeePageSplit = ieeePage.replace('<','>').split('>')
    title = None
    # find a tag that start with 'meta name="citation_title" content="'
    for i in ieeePageSplit:
        if i.startswith('meta name="citation_title" content="'):
            # get the paper title
            title = i.split('"')[3]
            break
    # a file name cannot be longer than 255 character (theoretically)
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx 
    return title.strip()[:150]

# get title for Science Direct paper
# the Science Direct paper filename is looks like this '1-s2.0-0031320375900217-main.pdf'
def getScienceDirectTittle(fname):
    # get url
    number = fname.split('-')[2]
    targeturl = 'http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/'+number
    # open and read from those url
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    sdPage = opener.open(targeturl).read()
    # split  every tag in the html. this is the stupid part :p
    sdPageSplit = sdPage.replace('<','>').split('>')
    title = None
    for i in range(len(sdPageSplit)):
        if sdPageSplit[i].startswith('title'):
            title = sdPageSplit[i+1]
            break
    # a file name cannot be longer than 255 character (theoretically)
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx 
    return title.strip()[:150]

def batchRename(workingdir, site):
    # list all file in working directory
    files = [ fInput for fInput in listdir(workingdir) if isfile(join(workingdir,fInput)) ]
    # compiled regular expression for illegal filename character
    reIlegalChar = re.compile(r'([<>:"/\\|?*])')
    # rename all files
    for f in files:
        try:
            # find title
            if site == IEEE:
                title = getIEEETitle(f)
            elif site == SCIENCEDIRECT:
                title = getScienceDirectTittle(f)
            else:
                title = None

            if title:
                # remove illegal file name character
                fnew = reIlegalChar.sub(r' ', title) + '.pdf'
                print '{} --> {}'.format(f, fnew)
                # rename file
                rename((workingdir + f), (workingdir + fnew))
                print 'Success'
            else:
                print '{}\nFailed'.format(f)
        except:
            print '{}\nERROR'.format(f)
        # give some random delay, so we will not be blocked (hopefully) :p
        time.sleep(random.randrange(10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Please be patient, it takes time depending on your internet connection speed...'
    workingdir = 'C:\\Users\\dataq\\Downloads\\paper\\' 
    batchRename(workingdir, IEEE)
```

This code works for IEEE and Science Direct articles. You can place your articles in the `workingdir`. Of course you can change the value of `workingdir` to your own folder.

In that code I rename the IEEE articles in folder `C:\Users\dataq\Downloads\paper\`. If you want to rename the Science Direct articles you have to change `batchRename(workingdir, IEEE)` to `batchRename(workingdir, SCIENCEDIRECT)`

You have to make sure that the articles file name is original (The original IEEE articles is looks like this: `06089032.pdf` and for Science Direct articles is looks like this: `1-s2.0-0031320375900217-main.pdf`)

I am not guarantee that these tools can work well, so use it at your own risk.